# How can I implement a modulo operation on unsigned ints with limited hardware in C

Tags: c, algorithm, math, numbers

I have a machine which only supports 32 bit operations, long long does not work on this machine.
I have one 64 bit quantity represented as two unsigned int 32s.
The question is how can I perform a mod on that 64 bit quantity with a 32 bit divisor.

r = a mod b

where:

a is 64 bit value and b is 32 bit value

I was thinking that I could represent the mod part by doing:
a = a1 * (2 ^ 32) + a2 (where a1 is the top bits and a2 is the bottom bits)

(a1 * (2 ^32) + a2) mod b = ( (a1 * 2 ^ 32) mod b + a2 mod b) mod b

( (a1 * 2 ^ 32) mod b + a2 mod b) mod b = (a1 mod b * 2 ^ 32 mod b + a2 mod b) mod b

but the problem is that 2 ^ 32 mod b may sometimes be equal to 2 ^ 32 and therefore the multiplication will overflow. I have looked at attempting to convert the multiplication into an addition but that also requires me to use 2 ^ 32 which if I mod will again give me 2 ^ 32 :) so I am not sure how to perform an unsigned mod of a 64 bit value with a 32 bit one.

I guess a simple solution to this would be to perform the following operations:

1. a / b = c
2. a = a - floor(c) * b
3. perform 1 until c is equal to 0 and use a as the answer.

but I am not sure how to combine these two integers together to form the 64 bit value

Just to be complete here are some links for binary division and subtractions:
http://www.exploringbinary.com/binary-division/

and a description of binary division algorithm:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm

Comment: Does the C compiler for your hardware not already support this?  E.g. `uint64_t a,b,r;  r = a % b;`

Comment: "2 ^ 32 mod b may sometimes be equal to 2 ^ 32".  Suggest not.  `b <= (2 ^ 32 - 1)`, so `(2 ^ 32 mod b) < (2 ^ 32)`.

Comment: You did figure out what's there to gain considering `a` as a number represented in a positional number system using base 2³², and what problem remains - not half bad. Now, what about base 2¹⁶? 2¹⁶±1? (And what about Chinese?)

Comment: @ Jonathon Reinhart: the fun part would be looking at the code generated (for variable `a` and `b`). _After_ giving _what can I come up with myself_ a half decent try.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Jonathan, no the C compiler I am using does not support uint64_t (Yes I know its surprising and it sucks).

Comment: @chux you are right about your comment, I think I may have explained it wrongly, if you separate 2^32 mod b to 2^16 mod b * 2^16 mod b then you get a chance whereby the mod would return 2^16 for both cases which in turn would again give you 2^32 gaining nothing :( You cant do a 2^32 mod b since 2^32 is > 32 bits

Comment: "can't do a `2^32 mod b`" --> true, but the trick is `2^32 mod b` == `(2^32 - b) mod b`.  We know at least 1 `b` can be subtracted from `2^32` without the result becoming negative.  With a loop shifting 1 bit at a time, that is all that is needed.

Comment: 2^32 mod b != 2^32 since b < 2^32 on your machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works: Tested with 1000M random combinations against a 64-bit `%`.

Like grade school long division `a/b` (but in base 2), subtract `b` from `a` if possible, then shift, looping 64 times.  Return the remainder.

```
#define MSBit 0x80000000L
uint32_t mod32(uint32_t a1 /* MSHalf */, uint32_t a2 /* LSHalf */, uint32_t b) {
  uint32_t a = 0;
  for (int i = 31+32; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (a & MSBit) {  // Note 1
      a <<= 1;
      a -= b;
    } else {
      a <<= 1;
    }
    if (a1 & MSBit) a++;
    a1 <<= 1;
    if (a2 & MSBit) a1++;
    a2 <<= 1;
    if (a >= b)
      a -= b;
  }
  return a;
}
```

Note 1: This is the sneaky part to do a 33-bit subtraction.  Since code knows `n` has the MSBit set, `2*n` will be greater than `b`, then `n = 2*n - b`.  This counts on unsigned wrap-around.

---

[Edit]

Below is a generic `modu()` that works with any array size `a` and any size unsigned integer.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>

// Use any unpadded unsigned integer type
#define UINT uint32_t
#define BitSize (sizeof(UINT) * CHAR_BIT)
#define MSBit ((UINT)1 << (BitSize - 1))

UINT modu(const UINT *aarray, size_t alen, UINT b) {
  UINT r = 0;
  while (alen-- > 0) {
    UINT a = aarray[alen];
    for (int i = BitSize; i > 0; i--) {
      UINT previous = r;
      r <<= 1;
      if (a & MSBit) {
        r++;
      }
      a <<= 1;
      if ((previous & MSBit) || (r >= b)) {
        r -= b;
      }
    }
  }
  return r;
}

UINT modu2(UINT a1 /* MSHalf */, UINT a2 /* LSHalf */, UINT b) {
  UINT a[] = { a2, a1 };  // Least significant at index 0
  return modu(a, sizeof a / sizeof a[0], b);
}
```

Comment: @crux could you please clarify if this would be returning a uint32_t or a int32_t?

Comment: @Har  Yes, thanks.  The return value should have been `uint32_t` and not `int32_t`. Answer updated.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the Note that you have written, I am finding it difficult to follow. If you have 0x80000000 and you left shift by 1 then you will get 0 (on a uint32_t) so the information is lost. I understand that you can tell if that will happen but I don't understand what the fix is. (this scenario occurs if a and b both have the top bit set but the rest of the bits are different) Is this because you know that for both a and b the top bits are set you are taking advantage of this?

Comment: @Har True, when `a` MSbit is set, the left shift will lose that bit, but then code is inside the `if() { }` blocks that "knows" the MSBit was shifted out. Thus the "33-bit" `a` is `0x1_0000_0000 + a`.  Since that is greater than `b`, code subtracts.  Unsigned int math is well-defined in C to "wrap-around".  So the result of `a -= b;` is mathematically correct here as it is the same `a = 0x1_0000_0000 + a - b`.  IMO, the following generic code does this better.

Comment: @Har "A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow, because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting type." C11dr §6.2.5 9  IOW, the result of 32-bit subtraction is `a-b mod 0x1_0000_0000`.

Comment: I still find that like magic but yes I get what your saying: (0x180000000 - 0x12345) mod 2**32 is the same as (0x80000000 - 0x12345) mod 2 ** 32 (modulo magic!)

Answer (score 3):

Do it the same way you would do a long division with pencil and paper.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int numh = 0x12345678;
unsigned int numl = 0x456789AB;
unsigned int denom = 0x17234591;

int main() {
    unsigned int numer, quotient, remain;

    numer = numh >> 16;
    quotient = numer / denom;
    remain = numer - quotient * denom;

    numer = (remain << 16) | (numh & 0xffff);
    quotient = numer / denom;
    remain = numer - quotient * denom;

    numer = (remain << 16) | (numl >> 16);
    quotient = numer / denom;
    remain = numer - quotient * denom;

    numer = (remain << 16) | (numl & 0xffff);
    quotient = numer / denom;
    remain = numer - quotient * denom;

    printf("%X\n", remain);   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: BTW: Do not get the same answer as `printf("%llX\n", 0x12345678456789ABu % 0x17234591u);`  `1042DD6` vs. `DF555C0`.

Comment: I think the problem is that if `demon` is more that 16 bits, `remain` may be more than 16 bits.  Then `(remain << 16)` throws bits away.

Comment: Yes the overflow issues is what make it the most trickiest. It seems the only reliable way to do this for all numbers is to ignore mathematics and go the "bit" way